# symlink makes a file that copies target file

Tags: symlink

I'm trying to make a link (called `mass`) from `~` to a target in `~/Documents`. I have tried this command:

`$ ln -s Documents/mass.gnumeric mass`

However, that produces a file `~/mass` that, when double-clicked in Nautilus, produces a *copy of the target file* in `~`, called `~/mass (1)`.

The behavior I expect is that double clicking `~/mass` should open up `~/Documents/mass.gnumeric` in the gnumeric app.

Why is this copying happening and how can I change it?

Comment: What makes you certain the `ln -s` command creates the copy, and not Nautilus?

Comment: Actually, that's a good point. I just figured the flaw would be with what I did, and Nautilus would deliver straightforward behavior.

Comment: You could verify that the link is not the problem by opening the file with a text editor (like nano or vim), and observing results. Do you alter anything with Nautilus? Most likely is that it removes the "file" (actually the link) before saving it. You could check if the new file is written at the time you click on it, or when you exit.